# Why doesn't adjusting these parameters shift the asymptotes?

Tags: functions

I used R to plot this function:

```
foo <- function(theta, a, b, c, d, D = (pi / sqrt(3)) * (15 / 16)) {(c + (d - c)) * (exp(D * a * (theta - b)) / (1 + exp(D * a * (theta - b))))}
theta <- theta <- runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 1)
plot(x = theta, y = foo(theta = theta, a = 4, b = 0.5, c = 0.25, d = 0.75), xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1))
```

From this paper:
http://apm.sagepub.com/content/early/2013/02/14/0146621613475471
[image]

which, according to the paper, when I shift `c` should change the lower asymptote on the plot and `d` should change the upper asymptote. But it isn't. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please avoid unecessary information. Is it correct that you want to plot the function $\theta \mapsto c+(d-c)\frac{\exp(a(\theta-b))}{1+\exp(a(\theta-b))}$ for some values of $a,b,c,d$? Note that a change of $c$ only results in a scaling in $y$ direction w.rt. $y=c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentheses are wrong in

```
(c + (d - c))
```

The expression adds up to `d` (effectively wiping out the `c`), whereas only the

```
(d - c)
```

should be multiplied onto what follows.